# Is $G(x)=\int_0^x \left| \frac{d}{dt}\int_{t-1}^tf(s)ds \right|dt$ bounded by the total variation of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Following up on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284362/is-the-function-gx-int-0x-left-fracddt-int-t-1tfsds-rightdt):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continously differentiable bounded function. For $x>0$, let 
$$
G(x)=\int_0^x \left| \frac{d}{dt}\int_{t-1}^tf(s)ds \right|dt.
$$

**Question:** Prove or disprove that $G(x)$ is bounded by the [total variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) of the function $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $G$ can be written as
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x |f(t) - f(t-1)|\, dt = 
\int_0^x \left|\int_{t-1}^t f'(s)\, ds\right| dt,
$$
hence
$$
G(x) \leq \int_0^x \int_{t-1}^t |f'(s)|\, ds\, dt =: B(x), 
\qquad \forall x>0.
$$
Let us estimate $B(x)$ using Fubini-Tonelli's theorem. 
Since $f\in C^1$, we have that
$$
B(x) \leq \int_{-1}^x\left(\int_s^{s+1} |f'(s)|\,dt\right)ds
= \int_{-1}^x |f'(s)|\, dt = T.V.(f, [-1,x]).
$$